# value of variable change event when don't do operation on them

Tags: c++

I have this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<cstdio>
#include<conio.h>
#include<windows.h>
#define BOARDSIZE 3
using namespace std;

int board[BOARDSIZE][BOARDSIZE];
int cnt = 0;
int minCount = BOARDSIZE*BOARDSIZE;

void boardSwitch(int x, int y){
    for(int i = x-1; i <= x+1; i++){
        for(int j = y-1; j <= y+1; j++){
            if((i>=0) && (j>=0)){
                board[i][j] = board[i][j] ^ 1;
            }
        }
    }
}

bool isOn(){
    int i, j;

    for(i = 0; i < BOARDSIZE; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < BOARDSIZE; j++){
            if(!board[i][j]){
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

void boardDisp(){
    for(int i = 0; i <BOARDSIZE; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < BOARDSIZE; j++){
            cout<<board[i][j]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
}

void turn(int x){
    int i, j;

    j = x%BOARDSIZE;
    i = (x-j)/BOARDSIZE;
    if(x == 0){
        cnt = 0;
    }
    for(int k = 0; k <=1; k++){
        printf("%d \n", cnt);
        cout<<i<<" "<<j<<" cnt = "<<cnt<<endl;
        //getch();
        if(k == 1){
            boardSwitch(i, j);  //switch on (i,j) position
            //cout<<i<<" "<<j<<" cnt = "<<cnt<<endl;
            //cnt++;
            //cout<<"switch on "<<i<<" "<<j<<" cnt = " <<cnt<<endl;
        }
        if(x == BOARDSIZE*BOARDSIZE-1){
//          if(isOn()){
//              minCount = minCount < cnt ? minCount : cnt;
//          }
        }
        else{
            turn(x+1);
        }
    }
    boardSwitch(i, j);  // return status before switch
    //cnt--;
}


int main(){
    for(int i = 0; i < BOARDSIZE; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < BOARDSIZE; j++){
            board[i][j] = rand()%2;     }
    }
    boardDisp();
    turn(0);
    if(minCount == BOARDSIZE*BOARDSIZE){
        //There is no way to turn board on
        cout<<"There is no way to turn board on";
    }else{
        cout<<minCount;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In my thought cnt is global variable and every function can change it's value. But there is no function change it's value but when i run that code (by code block, visual c++) sometime it print out value 1 for cnt variable and somtine 0. I see no operation can make change value of cnt but it's does change. why is that ?

Comment: Because you're writing outside the bounds of `board`. Don't do that.

Answer (score 1):

With the code commented as you have it, turn() keeps calling itself with increasing values of x until you get to turn(8).

At that point, i gets set to '2' and j gets set to '2'.  Then, you call boardSwitch(2,2).

Your problem happens in boardSwitch().  Your for() loop keeps going until both i and j are equal to 3, ultimately resulting in a write to board[3][3].  This location doesn't exist, so you are just writing off the end of the variable -- at that point, anything could get clobbered.  In your case, cnt is getting overwritten.

The main point is that there is nothing to prevent you from writing off the end of an array in c/c++.  You just start writing to memory that isn't what you thought it was, and the program begins to behave unpredictably.

Ultimately you need to fix your logic.  One thing you might try in the meantime is creating a function to wrap writes to the array and perform bounds checking for you.  For example:

```
    void writeToBoard(int i, int j, int value) {
        if (i >= BOARDSIZE) {
            printf("ERROR: Attempted to write outside array.\n");
            return;
        } else if(j >= BOARDSIZE) {
            printf("ERROR: Attempted to write outside array.\n");
            return;
        } else {
             board[i][j] = value;
        }             
    }
```

Then replace ALL writes to the array with calls to this function.

This would catch the problem when it happens in an easier to debug way.

Wrapping the board in an object, making that object private, and exposing this sort of thing as a member function is an excellent example of encapsulation.

An even better solution is to use standard library containers that do this thing for you (efficiently).  That isn't always an option, and it's good to know conceptually how this sort of thing works.  As a rule, though, there is very rarely a reason to implement your own bounds checked array.  That's why we have the standard library.